how to scroll to the top in react three fiber
so, I'm trying to make a project in react three fiber,this is my first time working with three and react three fiber. I have a 3d scene which has scrollControls and some html. I'm not able to do scroll to the top
I've tried to do scroll.offset = 0 and that moves the scroll to the top but immediately goes back to the bottom. Top is a state which changes with a click
here is a code snippet, I thing it's useframe is the reason but I don't know how to solve this.


   const scroll = useScroll() 
 
  useEffect(() => {    
scroll.offset = 0
  },[top])

  useFrame(() => {
    tl.current.seek(scroll.offset * tl.current.duration())
    tl2.current.seek(scroll.offset * tl2.current.duration())

    const content = document.getElementById('App');
    const totalHeight = content.clientHeight;
    let scrollDist = totalHeight*scroll.offset
    window.scrollTo({
      top:scrollDist,
      behavior:"smooth"
    })
    
  })



